# Memory implications fragment creation (create in each fragment transaction)

Tags: android, android-fragments, performance, android-memory

I have a doubt about the memory implications of fragments. What will be the most optimum solution in terms of memory:

1) create one object for each fragment and use these objects in the transaction manager.

```
MyFragment myFrag=new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainPager, myFrag);
```

2) create the fragment directly in the transaction manager and leave that the Garbage collector take account of this object, I mean something like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainPager, new MyFragment());
```

Are there any difference between the two options in terms of possible memory leaks and performance optimisation.

Thanks!

Comment: do you means: MyFragment myFrag = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainPager, myFrag);

Comment: 2) is safer if you mess it up. 1) is better if you do it right since you don't have to recreate objects. right vs wrong = detached fragment does not use lot's of memory and has no more reference to context that it could leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyFragment myFrag=new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainPager, myFrag);
```

This does not double the memory load. myFrag is just a reference to the new fragment, it only stores the memory location of the fragment, therefore the overload is negligible.

Comment: My doubt is in the next step, when the user change the fragment I will have a strong reference to the fragment. On the contrary, using the option 2 I will have a weak reference to the object so the Garbage Collector in theory will in charge to destroy it. isn't it?

Comment: It depends where myFrag is created: if it is a field that belongs to the fragment's hosting activity, the reference will stay, and you should be careful with this because the OS manages fragments' instances its own way. However, if the transaction is in a method, then myFrag is local and gets GC'd after the method returns. Was that your question?